# Remove the default Loading spinner from facebook in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want to remove the default `Facebook` login spinner from the app (At the time of signup with facebook). I followed the related questions on StackOverflow and most of them are suggesting to use

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`

in `FacebookActivity`. After adding above them. I can still see the default progress bar. How can I achieve it?

Any hint or help would be appreciable.

[image]